# добавить элемент по середине цикла

Tags: php, pdo, while

Здравствуйте как можно добавить элемент по середине выполнения цикла и затем продолжить его выполнение.Вот пример цикла:

```
while ($date= $sql->fetch()) {  //цикл 1 выводит 10 записей
echo $date['title'];
echo $date['img'];
echo $date['text'];
}
while ($rekl= $sqlrekl->fetch()) {  //цикл 2 выводи записи
echo $date['title'];
echo $date['img'];
echo $date['text'];
}
```

По середине его выполнения нужно вывести другой цикл, затем продолжить выполнение первого.
Пример выполнения:

```
Запись1
..
Запись5

//Второй цикл

Запись6
..
Запись10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

допустим что объект pdo всё таки то.

```
$date = $sql->fetch();
$dataArray = iterator_to_array($date);

for($i=0;$i<count($dataArray);$i++) {
   echo $dataArray[$i]['title'];
   // etc ....
   if($i==cail(count($dataArray)/2)) {
      while ($rekl= $sqlrekl->fetch()) {  //цикл 2 выводи записи
          echo $rekl['title']; // тут я думаю ошибка по этому date на rekl
          echo $rekl['img'];
          echo $rekl['text'];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: if($i==cail(count($data)/2))   $data откуда берется данная переменная?

Comment: @user209681 sorry опечатался это `$dataArray` поправил ответ

Comment: не cail, а ceil

Comment: не работает, не выводит ниодну запись

Comment: `var_dump($dataArray);die;` перед циклом что показывает?

Comment: ничего не показывает

Comment: Прошу прощение, выводит. Заменил fetch() на fetchall() и убрал iterator_to_array.

Answer (score -2):

Достаточно ввести счетчик $i, в конце первого цикла добавлять ему единичку на каждой итерации, а там где необходимо вывести второй цикл добавить условия проверки счетчика.

```
$i=0;
while ($date= $sql->fetch()) 
{
   echo $date['title'];
   echo $date['img'];
   echo $date['text'];
   if($i==5)
   {
      while ($rekl= $sqlrekl->fetch()) {  //цикл 2 выводи записи
          echo $date['title'];
          echo $date['img'];
          echo $date['text'];
      }
   }
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: кастыль лучше `fetch` на `fetchAssoc` заменить. А `while` на `for`, и далее `if($i==5)` на `if($i==cail(count($date))` ну и вывод на что то подобное `$date[$i]['title']`

Comment: @Naumov Подскажите пожалуйста пример кода.

Comment: И почему не подходит вариант EatMyDust

Comment: @user209681 да потому что записей у вас может быть и 10,15, 8,4,5 это рас, если в `while` ввести i++ и условие то это уже `for`. плюсом он не на середине а на 6 элементе выводит данные

Comment: в условии "//цикл 1 выводит 10 записей" не знаю что там может быть, как спросили так и ответил

Comment: если n количество записей то да - используйте count()